# Could much of the "missing" antimatter make up neutrons?

Tags: antimatter, neutrons

A neutron can decay into a proton, an electron, and neutrino.  Could an antiproton, a positron, and a neutrino combine into a neutron?  Could this be where much of the "missing" antimatter is?

Comment: well, this is completely non sense as far as quantum numbers go.neutron-->proton electron anti_e_neutrino. antineutron--> antiproton positron e_neutrino.

Comment: The neutron is not its own antiparticle. The antineutron is a distinct particle. It happens to have the same charge as the neutron (zero), but it has other characteristics that distinguish it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that by "negatron" you mean a anti-proton, then **no**. It violated the conservation of baryon number (for aproton $B = -1$ and for a neutron $B = 1$)  and in any case, free neutrons are unstable--it's not just that they *can* decay, they *will* decay.

Worse still, neutrons *do* interact with light, albeit with a low corss-section because they are composites of charge quarks and gluons.

Comment: That is what I meant by "negatron".